# Mobile Resizable Window Dropdown Menu Doesnt Work

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok so I'm attempting a mobile resizable window. When I tried running it, it doesn't work and I don't know why. Here is my html code:

```js
    const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
    const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

    menu.addEventListener('click', function() {
      menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
      menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  background: #131313;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
  background-color: #ff8177;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ff0844 0%, #ffb199 100%);
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.fa-gem {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar__item {
  height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #f77062;
  color: #fff;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #4837ff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
  color: #f77062;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .navbar__menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 50vh;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #131313;
  }

  .navbar__menu.active {
    background: #131313;
    top: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 50vh;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

  #navbar__logo {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }

  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
  }

  .navbar__item {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar__links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  .navbar__btn {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  #mobile-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    right: 5%;
    transform: translate(5%, 20%);
  }

  .navbar__toggle .bar {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
  }

  #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>HTML CSS Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__container">
        <a href="/" id="navbar__logo"><i class="fas fa-gem"></i> AigoLearningJuniorTeam </a>
        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar__menu">
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Our Team</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/tech.html" class="navbar__links"> Weekly Challenges </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item">
            <a href="/" class="navbar__links"> Monthly Challenges </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__btn"><a href="/" class="button"> Get Started </a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script>src="app.js"</script>
  </body>
```

Everything works perfectly fine until I resize my window into a mobile version, the drop menu icon shows, but when I press on it, nothing happens.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wecozayoqa/edit?html,css,js,output 

This is working right here

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem you're talking about.

Comment: When I run it with live Server in visual studio code it doesn't work. Is it just a bug on my end? I tested the link that you just used and it works.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Have you tried clearing your browser caches? It might be that you still have an older version of your CSS file cached.

Comment: What are you guys using to test my code? I'm using the Liver Server extension from visual studio code. Maybe is live server the fault? Can someone else test it with the live server extension on visual studio code? I also tried clearing the browser caches and it didn't work

Comment: I just hosted my website via Github Pages. https://pandaman456.github.io/AJT/ Can anyone test this out? The dropdown menu doesn't work for me